# Force method to wait for Markers creation before to call next method in a callback method

Tags: javascript, typescript, google-maps, async-await, promise

I am making an app using the Google maps library with a callback function calling two sets of processes.

I want to be sure the first process is finished before the second one is launched.

This means I would like the callbackHandler method to wait for all the markers made in method createChargerPointMarkers() to be created, pushed and set on the map before to call calculateAndDisplayRoute(), but it does not.

Instead it waits patiently until the last loop but launches the calculateAndDisplay method before the last loop is really finished

Let's say you have 3 loops, what happens is :
"Loop 1  out of 3"
(you can see markers being set on map)
"Loop 2 out of 3"
(you can see markers being set on map)
"Loop 3 out of 3"
"EV markers creations finished"
"route calculation started"
And only after that will you see the markers of the last loop being created and set on the map.

I suppose I am organizing promises/await wrongly. How can I force the compiler to wait for all the markers to be created and set before to continue ?

Remark : It is difficult/not possible to show a reproductible functionning example of this because the polyline creation methods use an external library (epolys.js, very useful) and without it the code is not understandable by CodePen and JSFiddle. You also need more code to create Google Map, Markers etc. so it would be too much code to put here

I can share the repo if you are willing to see the whole code but it is long (441 lines so far) and only the methods I put here are relevant to this problem.

```
chargingPointsMarkers = [];
markerArray = [];

async callbackHandler(startEndPointsArray, calculateAndDisplayRoute): Promise<void> {
    await this.setChargingStationsMarkers();
    calculateAndDisplayRoute();
  }

  calculateAndDisplayRoute(): Promise<void> {
    console.log('calculation started')
  }

  async setChargingStationsMarkers(): Promise<void> {

    const polyline = await this.createPolyline();
    const polylineMarkersArray = await this.createMarkersOnPolyline(polyline);
    // This makes a Google Polyline object.I voluntarily did not include the polyline methods, 
   // they are not relevant and are resolved before the following loop starts

    const baseUrl = 'https://api.openchargemap.io/v3/poi/output=json&maxresults=100&verbose=false&includecomments=true';

    for (let j = 0; j < polylineMarkersArray.length - 1; j++) {

      const origin = polylineMarkersArray[j].getPosition();
      const destination = polylineMarkersArray[j + 1].getPosition();

      const route = await this.createRoute(origin, destination);

      const encodedPolyline = route.overview_polyline;
      const queryUrl = baseUrl + '&polyline=' + encodedPolyline + '&distance=50';

      await fetch(queryUrl)
        .then((response) => response.json())
        .then( async (data) => await this.createChargerPointMarkers(data))
        .then (() => {
                   const k = j + 1;
          const l = polylineMarkersArray.length - 1;
          if (j === polylineMarkersArray.length - 2) {
            console.log('loop ' + k + ' of ' + l);
            console.log('EV markers creation finished');
          }else{
            console.log('loop ' + k + ' of ' + l);
          }
        });

    }
  }

async createChargerPointMarkers(jsonChargingPoints): Promise<void> {
    // Convert the Json response elements to Google Markers, places them on the Map and pushes them to an array.
    for (const item of jsonChargingPoints) {
      const LatLng = new google.maps.LatLng(parseFloat(item.AddressInfo.Latitude), parseFloat(item.AddressInfo.Longitude));
      const marker = await new google.maps.Marker({
        position: LatLng,
        map: this.map,
        draggable: false,
      });
      this.markerArray.push(marker);
      this.chargingPointsMarkers.push(marker);
    }
  }

  async createRoute(point1, point2): Promise<google.maps.DirectionsRoute> {
    // Returns a Google DirectionsRoute object
    const directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
    const request = {
      origin: point1,
      destination: point2,
      travelMode: google.maps.TravelMode.DRIVING,
      unitSystem: google.maps.UnitSystem.METRIC
    };
    return new Promise(resolve => directionsService.route(request,
      (result, status) => {
        if (status === 'OK') {
          resolve(result.routes[0]);
        } else {
          window.alert('Directions request failed due to ' + status);
        }
      })
    );
  }
```

Comment: You should be able to include an external library to a stack snippet or codepen and such or to include the code inline. Or you could get rid of the code that makes use of the library. In any case you should be able to provide a [mcve].

Comment: @MrUpsidedown Actually I tried, I realize it would be easier to get answers with it. The library is used in the createMarkersOnPolyline that is called here by adding a GetPointAtDistance method to polylines and whatever I tried I get a compiler error even when when putting the epolys.js in another codepen and importing it.

Comment: If the issue is with your multiple async/await can you not simply get rid of that part of the code that calls the external library, or simplify it somehow? And btw. you haven't included that part of the code or have you?

Comment: @MrUpsidown I managed to create a reproductible example. I will create another question with it. Thanks for your comments.

Comment: @LindaPaiste They are both mine. This is the other question with a reproducible example I mentioned in my last comment